# Button size in table row

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

I have 4 images in Table row:

```
<TableRow
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="Icon"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_android"
                    />
                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="Icon"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_android"
                    />
                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="Icon"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_android"
                    />
                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="Icon"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_android"
                    />

</TableRow>
```

Why I'm getting two big buttons and two small ones as result. Why they are not same size?

[image]

Comment: Have you missed `android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for tableRow?

Comment: add layout_weight for each buttons and may be wrap to linear layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `layout_weight` property to equally divide the space among four views. Remember to set the `layout_width` to 0dp.

```
<ImageButton
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_margin="4dp"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:contentDescription="Icon"
     android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
```

Sample Output :

[image: Sample]